# get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given. Why is this error occuring? What is the solution for this?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, post, django-models

I was working on a comment of a blog project. When I typed the code to handle the POST request in the views.py but was getting a error. This was the error 'get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given'.

models.py

```py
class commenttable(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, default=0)
    blog = models.TextField()
    comment_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    comment_email = models.EmailField()
    comment_Text = models.TextField()
    comment_date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.comment_Text
```

views.py

```py
from .models import commenttable

...

def post_comment(request, blog_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.POST.get("name", "email", "comment")
       # blog = get_object_or_404(Blog_tables, pk=blog_id)
        p = commenttable(blog= data.name, comment_name=data.email, comment_email= data.email, comment_Text= data.comment, comment_data = timezone.now())
        p.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
    else:
        return render(request, '/blogs/' + blog_id + '/comment', {'error_message': 'Error'})
```

This is the form :

```py
<form action="/blogs/{{blog_id}}/comment" method ="post">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name"/>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email"/>
            <input type="text" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="Comments here"/>

            <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
        </form>
```

I want to get the data from POST request and save it to the database.
But writing this code gives me error 'get() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not obtain multiple elements with:

```
data = request.POST.get('name', 'email', 'comment')
```

The [**`QueryDict.get(..)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) takes one or two *explicit* parameters. The first value is the *key*, and the second one is an *optional* default (if you do not provide one, `None` will be used).

You thus can obtain the data with:

```
name = request.POST.get('name')
email = request.POST.get('email')
comment = request.POST.get('comment')
blog = get_object_or_404(Blog_tables, pk=blog_id)
p = commenttable.objects.create(
    blog=blog,
    comment_name=name,
    comment_email=email,
    comment_Text=comment,
    comment_data=timezone.now()
)
```